# How do I automate the OAuth verification step?

Tags: java, twitter, oauth-2.0, social-networking, scribe

I'm trying to build an app that accesses a user's Twitter feed. I'm using the Java [Scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/wiki/getting-started) project for this.

However the module requires the user to manually enter a verification code each time a request is made. Is there any way I can  automate / avoid the user verification step that occurs each time after the initial permissions to the app are granted?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have an OAuth access code, you can continue to use that code for a long as it's valid. You can store that access code (encrypted of course) and use it each time your user makes a request. For security, you'll probably want to use some other kind of authentication system on top of your own app, like an email/password combination, but that is up to you.

Honestly, I would advise you to continue doing what you're doing now. Access to users accounts should be handled respectfully and with great concern over security. By continuing to rely on Twitter's OAuth service, you remove a lot of the security burden from yourself. It's similar to storing Credit Card information: Can you do it? Sure. *SHOULD* you do it? Probably not if you're considering the best interests of your users or you are prepared to invest heavily into the privacy and security of your users.

Hope this helps.